# Active CSS form background

Tags: html, wordpress, css

I have a wordpress website and a form. I would like that when a radio button is active its background container would have a color background. I have successfully accomplished that with CSS with these two classes

```
.ezfc-inline.ezfc-element-radio-container {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
.ezfc-inline.ezfc-element-radio-container:active {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #105CAB;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

but the problem is that I have to physically hold the mouse button on the element to keep it active. As soon as I let go the background disappear.

Any input would be very appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean that if the radio button is selected it should show the background? Edit: to be clear, I meant if it is checked.

Comment: Something like this .ezfc-inline.ezfc-element-radio-container[type="radio"]:checked

Comment: When I add this it does not seem to make any effect I have tried a few more solutions from the link below but they did not seem to work too.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add the `:checked` state.

```
.ezfc-inline.ezfc-element-radio-container {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.ezfc-inline.ezfc-element-radio-container:active, .ezfc-inline.ezfc-element-radio-container .ezfc-element-radio input:checked {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #105CAB;
color: #FFF;
}
```

I'm not sure of your HTML structure but i would hazard a guess that the input is within the container class.

You can read more about `:checked` elements [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked)

Comment: Its due to your HTML structure. See the amended answer

Comment: When I apply 

input[type="radio"]:checked {
  margin-left: 25px;
}

It works but I cannot apply it on a specific css class or a container